# Loading point of interests from url using leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I never used leaflet before. I'm trying to draw some points with custom icons over an OpenStreetMap layer. I would like to load those points from a file url, but I don't know how.
The file format is not important: it's generated by my program and I could change the output type.

I'm sure that the answer it's an easy one, but the only examples I found use informations that are hard coded in the main javascript block.

How could I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution:

```
L.geoJson(data, {
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.title);
    },
    pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
        var myicon = L.icon({
            iconUrl: feature.properties.icon,
            iconSize: [24, 24],
            iconAnchor: [0, 24],
            popupAnchor: [12, -32],
        })
        return L.marker(latlng, {icon:myicon});
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

`data` is defined like this:

```
<script src="geojson.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

`geojson.js` is a normal geojson file, but it starts with `data =`

Source: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/leaflet-js/lWTj9jiB1yw/EKczooIpxjgJ